# Semantic UI - Why no message inside a Form?

Tags: html, css, forms, semantic-ui

I'm using `Semantic-UI` and I was trying to add a warning `message` to my `Form`, like this:

```
<form>
    ...stuff...
    <div class="ui warning message">
        <div class="header">
            Title of the message
        </div>
        Text of the message
    </div>
</form>
```

But for some reason it wasn't showing up at all on the page.
Only after I found out that it's because SemanticUI's own internal CSS rules explicitly hide messages inside forms. From `semantic.min.css`:

```
.ui.form .error.message, .ui.form .success.message, .ui.form .warning.message {
    display: none;
}
```

Why is this? Can I override it? Is there a reason why I shouldn't?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I'm not 100% sure, but I'm **guessing** that the `error` / `success` / `warning` classes are used for form validation messages, thus the reason they are hidden by default. I solved the issue by using the specific color class rather than the `warning` one:

```
<form>
    ...stuff...
    <div class="ui yellow message">
        <div class="header">
            Title of the message
        </div>
        Text of the message
    </div>
</form>
```

This works perfectly and is visually indistinguishable from the `warning` one.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue. Not sure if you already have the answer, but for others visiting this post:

wrap you `<form>` with `<div>` with class "ui form error".

E.g.,

```
<div class="ui form error">
<form class="some class" method="POST" action="/some_acton">
..fields..
</form>
</div>
```

or

```
<form class="ui form error your_class" method="POST" action="/some_action">
..fields..
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `visible` class to the message `div` works for me. Try this,

`<div class="ui warning visible message">`

Answer (score 2):

This was designed intentionally by Semantic-UI.

Putting error state to the form will make it works.

For **Semantic UI HTML/CSS**, check [here](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#error)

```
<div class="ui form error">
  <div class="field">
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="joe@schmoe.com">
  </div>
  <div class="ui error message">
    <div class="header">Action Forbidden</div>
    <p>You can only sign up for an account once with a given e-mail address.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui submit button">Submit</div>
</div>
```

For **Semantic UI React**, check [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-error)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Form, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FormExampleError = () => (
  <Form error>
    <Form.Input label='Email' placeholder='joe@schmoe.com' />
    <Message
      error
      header='Action Forbidden'
      content='You can only sign up for an account once with a given e-mail address.'
    />
    <Button>Submit</Button>
  </Form>
)

export default FormExampleError
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the visible property is hidden by default. You can dynamically set the visible property to true by using the `ngClass`. For example:

```
<form class="ui form">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="x"> x </label>
        <input type="text" id="x">
        <div class="ui error message" [class.visible]="true">Error!</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

or

```
<form class="ui form">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="x"> x </label>
        <input type="text" id="x">
        <div class="ui error message" [ngClass]="{visible : true}>Error!</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

your write in css `.form` `class` but you not used to `.form` `class` so  you can used only `form` `tag` in your css

try to this

```
form .ui.error.message, 
form .ui.success.message, 
form .ui.warning.message {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you even read what I wrote? Sorry, no offense, but this has nothing to do with my question. Point one: the CSS is the official one that comes with semantic-ui, it's not my CSS. Plus, I'm not trying to hide it, I'm trying to do the opposite. The CSS, in fact, is not incorrect, it works perfectly (which is what annoys me, as it hides my messages;))